# adobe AIR: prevent GC from running

Tags: actionscript-3, air, garbage-collection

For a game (using AIR for iOS) I want to prevent the GC from running during a specific 30 seconds sequence (because it causes very notable lags).

What I already do is calling System.gc() right before the sequence starts. During the sequence, i don't create many new objects and only some animations play and objects move (in 3D). some of the objects move out of the stage.

the memory statistics during this sequence are aproximately:

```
System.totalMemory: 4.5 MB
System.freeMemory: 1.0 MB
System.privateMemory: 75 MB
```

When the GC fires, the System.privateMemory drops to 74 MB, but causes a lag of aproximately one second. The GC fires twice during this 30 second sequence.

So my question is about any techniques, hacks or workarrounds (other than optimizing the memory usage in general - obviously i'm already working on that) to prevent the GC from firing during this 30 seconds?

thanks.

Comment: Do you have a lot of objects?

Comment: well - what's a lot - a few hundreds i'd say - but i'm not creating massively new ones during this sequence (i add maybe 50 display objects and remove them again during these 30 seconds)

Comment: would it help to create the object before the sequence, keep them invisible and just play with visibility to not alarm the GC with object creation/deletions...

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent GC from running. But I would like to note that there are two issues with calling `System.gc()`.

First, you should check if it is enabled. The [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#gc%28%29) says:

> For the Flash Player debugger version and AIR applications only. In an AIR application, the System.gc() method is only enabled in content running in the AIR Debug Launcher (ADL) or, in an installed application, in content in the application security sandbox.

Second, calling `System.gc()` just once, may not actually free memory. See here for more [information](http://www.craftymind.com/2008/04/09/kick-starting-the-garbage-collector-in-actionscript-3-with-air/).

Comment: i know about debug and installed application - but i assume that AIR for iOS is installed application?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can prevent garbage collection running.

Garbage collection runs because the system *needs* more resources and if the system runs out of resources your app will crash. Perhaps you should think of another way to perform your task that is less resource hungry.

Also be aware that using System.gc() in your code will only work in the debug version of Flash Player.

I think I also read somewhere that to correctly use System.gc() as part of your testing you should call it twice:

```
 System.gc();
 System.gc();
```

The first time to *mark* unused memory and the second to *sweep*.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/garbage_collection.html

Comment: it doesn't really seem to need memory. i reduced the memory footprint and the lag still occurs at exactly the same time. When it happens, memory usage of System.privateMemory drops down for a short moment (System.totalMemory and System.freeMemory don't seem to be affected at this moment). Could it be garbage collection that is not related to my ByteCode but to garbage collection of the AIR runtime itself?

Comment: Not sure. I wonder if using monster debugger might shed some light on what's going on. http://www.demonsterdebugger.com/

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it's not possible to prevent the GC from running. There are 2 possible approaches that may help to get rid of the lag:

1. make sure you hold on to all objects that are created during the animation until after the animation finishes. This however can give serious memory issues, all depending on the number of objects and their memory consumption
2. run System.gc() (twice) regularly during the animation, which will cause the memory cleansing to be distributed and hopefully will spread out the lag

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling `system.useForGCIfCollectionImminent()` before the sequence starts.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent() with a high imminence value (1)?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this by not creating garbage. This means, not having unreferenced objects, `null` objects, etc. When you know performance is not critical, you can destroy the objects by removing all references and making them `null`, and the GC will start doing it's work.

The GC will still be "looking for garbage", but it should use a lot less unexpected resources.

The thing with references is that all objects in AS3 are pointers to the "real" object, except for the primitive values such as int, uint, String, etc. This is easily verifiable

```
var a = new Object(); // we create an Object and a pointer called "a"
a.property = "I'm alive";
var b = a; // we create a pointer to the Object called "b"
a = null; // the Object still exists
trace(b.property) // I'm alive
b = null; // the Object still exists but is unreferenced, and will be GCed
trace(b.property) // Error
```

Keep this in mind when working with the GC.